# Help me understand odd CSS behaviour!

Tags: css

Odd CSS behavior. 
When i set the visited color using CSS(a.nav:hover as below example) then the hover doesn't work once the link is visited by the user. However when i set it with the reference of the parent element(.header a.nav:hover as below) it works. why ?

```
a.nav:visited{
color:yellow;
}

/*once the link is visited by user this rule not working*/
a.nav:hover{
color:red;
}

/*if we use this rule it works even after the link is visited*/
.header a.nav:hover{
color:red;
}

<div class="header">
<a class="nav" .. >test </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9S9h5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) issue. Do you have any other `a` pseudo-selectors in your CSS? If there's a selector which is more specific than `a.nav:hover` (such as `.header a.nav:hover`) then it will override it, regardless of its position in the file.

Comment: The official CSS2 specification, in case someone wants to read it: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity (and people should read it! the section about selector's specificity is easy to understand)

Comment: @Denilson Thanks for that. I linked to the one above because I think it's awesome to explain specificity with Star Wars :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.nav:hover,
a.nav:visited:hover{
color:red;
}
```

or

```
a.nav:hover{
color:red !important;
}
```

Should make it work.